# Blazorize DataGrid Render using dynamic column binding & data binding

Tags: blazor, blazor-server-side

I have list of columns for grid specified in a table 'Controls' containing the COLUMN_NAME & COLUMN_CAPTION and a SRNO with some other extra details which is not necessary here.

`public IEnumerable<ControlSettings> datagrid { get; set; }`
--> this contains the list of rows from above table.

`List<Dictionary<string, object>> gridData { get; set; } = new List<Dictionary<string, object>>();`
--> this contains data for the grid where dictionary key is set to be column_name from the above ControlSettings class.

```
<Blazorise.DataGrid.DataGrid Data="@gridData" TItem="Dictionary<string, object>">  
    <DataGridColumns>  
        @foreach (var column in datagrid)  
        {  
            <DataGridColumn TItem="Dictionary<string, object>" Field="@column.COLUMN_NAME" Caption="@column.COLUMN_CAPTION" />  
        }  
    </DataGridColumns>  
</Blazorise.DataGrid.DataGrid>
```

This is the code I used for displaying the grid. But the grid is not getting displayed & getting error.

Error is:

```
 ArgumentException: Cannot detect the member of System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2[System.String,System.Object] (Parameter 'LOC')
```

Note: LOC is one of the column_name

The issue might be because of dictionary usage.

please help me with any suggestions to make this code work.

I need a Datagrid with dynamic column & data binding without using any external class.

Answer (score 0):

DataGrid usually works by binding to the model class.

You can just remove the Data parameter and not define the Field on a column. To show the column value, use the DisplayTemplate inside of a column.